# List.h in linux files?

Tags: c, linux, list, unix

in [linux/include/linux/list.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/305230142ae0637213bf6e04f6d9f10bbcb74af8/include/linux/list.h#L600) I found:

```
/**
 * list_entry - get the struct for this entry
 * @ptr:    the &struct list_head pointer.
 * @type:   the type of the struct this is embedded in.
 * @member: the name of the list_head within the struct.
 */
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    container_of(ptr, type, member)
```

What do they mean by "get the struct for this entry" can I see a usage example to understand in a better way?

Comment: A macro is defined which calls a function with the same parameters.

Answer (score 3):

This is a great example of a kind of Polymorphism in C. To borrow terminology from C++, the `list_entry()` macro allows you to downcast from a `list_head` type to any type that contains it.

Have a look at `kthread.c` for a simple fundamental example:

kernel/kthread.c:

```
struct kthread_create_info
{
    /* Information passed to kthread() from kthreadd. */
    int (*threadfn)(void *data);
    void *data;
    int node;

    /* Result passed back to kthread_create() from kthreadd. */
    struct task_struct *result;
    struct completion *done;

    struct list_head list;
};

...
int kthreadd(void *unused)
{
...
        while (!list_empty(&kthread_create_list)) {
            struct kthread_create_info *create;

            create = list_entry(kthread_create_list.next,
                        struct kthread_create_info, list);
...
            create_kthread(create);
```

By including a `list_head` object in the `kthread_create_info` struct, you can say that `kthread_create_info` "derives" from `list_head`. This allows `kthread_create_info` objects to be used as nodes in a list, meaning you can pass them to any of the functions declared in `list.h` by simply dereferencing the `list` member of the struct. The `list_entry` macro then gives you the mapping from a base class pointer to its derived start address.

In other words, given a `list_head` object that you know is contained within an outer `kthread_create_info` struct, you can recover a pointer to the `kthread_create_info` container.

This is an extremely common pattern in C programming, where object oriented constructs are desired, but a C++ compiler isn't available.